# Как передать массив в конструктор в C++?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, visual-c++, конструктор

Я реализовываю свой класс vector, но у меня возникла проблема: как передать в конструктор массив в таком виде:
`ClassName object = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`?

Comment: Что значит "передать массив"? `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` сам по себе не является "массивом" и никакой "передачи массива" в вашем примере нет. Ответ на ваш вопрос сильно зависит от того, что вы собрались делать с передаваемыми данными дальше. Без этих деталей вопрос бессмыслен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в квадратных скобках - не подскажу.

А в фигурных - например, так:

```
class A
{
    vector<int> v;
public:
    A(initializer_list<int> l):v(l)
    {
        for(auto x: l) cout << x << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
}
```

Т.е. см. [`initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

Comment: Не помешало бы тогда дополнительно как этот список инициализации использовать, не делегируя его конструктору вектора... Но в принципе из документации реально всё понять, плюс примеров много...

Comment: @zcorvid Да без проблем... так сойдет?